# Reading the JAR values out of a properties file in Perl and then compare it with the local version

Tags: perl, maven, nexus

This might be a little too difficult to do with perl, but I'm hoping someone can at least help me find the correct direction to accomplish this.

Currently we have a Nexus server that is holding all of our .jar files. One of the applications needs to use 3rd party common jars that are being defined in a .properties file.

The properties file looks like this

```
commons-logging=commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-io=commons-io-2.3.jar
httpcore=httpcore-4.2.1.jar
```

I am being asked to create a Perl script that will skim through this properties file, then compare that version(i.e. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar) with a version that is located elsewhere. If the version in the properties file is not the same, it will then copy the new .jar file to the common jar location.

An example 
In C:\commons there is a commons-logging-1.1.0

In the properties file, it is specified that commons-logging=commons-logging-1.1.1.jar is needed. The perl script would then read the .properties file, determine that commons-logging-1.1.1 is not the same as the commons-logging-1.1.0 found in the commons folder and would replace it.

We can also use maven for something like this, but I'm not sure how we can make it so the developer can just define what jar is needed in a properties file and replace it in a specific folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why define dependencies in a properties file if you're using Maven? Define it in a Maven pom file, like you're supposed to--seems like you're re-inventing a well-known dependency resolution system. What's the specific issue you're having with the Perl script? Don't you just need to extract version strings and compare?

Comment: How would I go about extracting the version strings and comparing?

Comment: A solution might be to read that .properties file and then input the jar versions in to the maven POM file.

Comment: Regular expressions and a custom compare that does a point-wise compare of numerified number strings between the dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what problems you are having with this. Perhaps this program will help?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', '.properties' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
  if (/^([\w-]+)=\1-([\d.]+)\.jar$/) {
    my ($lib, $ver) = ($1, $2);
    print qq(Library "$lib" needs version $ver\n);
  }
  else {
    warn "Error in .properties line $.: $_";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
Library "commons-logging" needs version 1.1.1
Library "commons-io" needs version 2.3
Library "httpcore" needs version 4.2.1
```

Comment: I think this can work in combination of maven. I can have the output set the correct version in the pom.xml. However, I'm not quite sure how to set the localRepository to a commons folder in just this pom.xml instead of changing the settings.xml

Comment: @Heuristic: I'm afraid I can't help you with Maven

Comment: Now I'm thinking I'll use your snipit of code, then on the output do a maven set version for each $lib. Then doing a maven build, it will make sure that each of those jars are in the local repositories. Then I can pull down each jar from Nexus in to a local commons folder

Though, I probably want $lib and $ver to be arrays. Then after getting all of the values I can do a for each @lib

Comment: Hmm.. So I changed it so it's push(@lib,$1); and push(@ver,$2);

I want to set something up like foreach @lib, cmd cp $lib-$version.jar blahblahblah. However, I'm struggling to get each $lib/$version to print

Comment: Try `while (@lib) { my $lib = shift @lib; my $ver = shift @ver; print "$lib/$ver\n"; }`

Comment: That worked, thanks Borodin. This will at least get me going in the right direction.

Comment: I think they want to change directions on how the property file is listed out. It will now look like httpcore=httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1

The "httpcore=" isn't the important part, but I need to pull httpcomponents as $1 httpcore $2 and 4.2.1 as $3. What would be the regular expession for that? The rest I can figure out. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: Figured it out. The regex I used was, ([a-zA-z-]+):([\a-zA-Z]+):([\d.]+)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've been asked to write a dependency management client.

I would suggest using Apache ivy, which has a convenient [command-line client](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html).

## Example

This ivy command:

```
java -jar ivy.jar -ivy ivy.xml -retrieve "lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
```

creates a "lib" directory populated with the jars listed in the ivy file:

```
├── ivy.xml
└── lib
    ├── commons-io-2.3.jar
    ├── commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    └── httpcore-4.2.1.jar
```

The real advantage of this approach is that ivy will also download the transitive dependencies.

Additionally ivy will cache the files previously downloaded. This means it's simpler to just delete an older directory and get ivy to create a new directory containing the jars. (Rather than going to the effort of comparing files)

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="myorg" module="mymodule" />
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-io" name="commons-io" rev="2.3" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpcore" rev="4.2.1" conf="default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```